# Directive scope to the controller

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a directive, so that I can close the bootstrap-modal with the function within controller on success event. What I have tried is

```
//Directive
.directive('modalBox', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            console.log(element);
            scope.dismiss      = function() {
                element.modal('hide');
            };
            scope.dismissModal = function(inputClass) {
                $('.' + inputClass).modal('hide');
            };
        }
    };
});
```

HTML is like

```
<div id="myModal" data-backdrop="static" class="modal fade modalBox myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-xlg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header modal-header-danger">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h4 class="margin-none" ng-if="!operation">Add Fuel Entry</h4>
            <h4 class="margin-none" ng-if="operation">Update Fuel Entry</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">My Form Data
 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and with in controller I implement it like --

```
$scope.closeModal = function() {
      $scope.dismissModal('myModal'); 
};
```

Its giving me error of undefined. Where am I doing wrong.

Comment: Did you convert the directive from camelCase to kebab-case for the HTML.? ie use `modal-box` in the HTML?

Comment: I tried with that also.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a directive you should bind this `closeModal` methods inside the directive. As you're using bootstrap's modal form you should also consider to make use of angular-bootstrap component.

For this specific situation maybe you could remove this directive and interact with modal directly on the controller:

HTML:

```
<div id="myModal" data-backdrop="static" class="modal fade modalBox myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xlg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header modal-header-danger">
            <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="closeModal('myModal') aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h4 class="margin-none" ng-if="!operation">Add Fuel Entry</h4>
            <h4 class="margin-none" ng-if="operation">Update Fuel Entry</h4>
         </div>
      <div class="modal-body">My Form Data
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and on your controller:

```
$scope.closeModal = function(modalId) {
  $("#" + modalId).modal('hide');
};
```

Comment: I could close it from button, but thats not my question is. I wish to bind it to Directive and perform close functionality from their. In order to make comman method within whole app.

Comment: @Sankalp if you want to use it as a directive, isn't it a good idea to render the modal's HTML by using directive's `templateUrl` or `template` property?
Then you could bind the button methods not to the controller scope but to the directive scope. It seems to fit your needings in a better way...